# Pass a URL in a notification in Android

Tags: java, android, notifications

I have the following method written in Android Studio. This method will create a notification when a beacon is detected:

```
 public void showNotification(Beacon beacon) {

    Resources r = getResources();
    int random = (int) System.currentTimeMillis();
    Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setSmallIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_popup_reminder)
            .setContentTitle("You have reached area:" )
            .setContentText(retrieveLocation(beacon.get()))
            .setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_MAX)
            .setVibrate(new long[0])
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setLights(0xff00ff00, 300, 100)
            .build();

    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    notificationManager.notify(random, notification);
    }
```

Now I want to include a weblink that in this notification.  I have done some research online and understand that I need to create a context class.  However, I am still really confused as to how I can pass the link to the this method.     I am very new to java, so any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Send your url as a string in notification intent

```
public void showNotification(Beacon beacon) {
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString("url", "www.google.com");
  Resources r = getResources();
   int random = (int) System.currentTimeMillis();
    Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setSmallIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_popup_reminder)
            .setContentTitle("You have reached area:" )
            .setContentText(retrieveLocation(beacon.get()))
            .setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_MAX)
            .setVibrate(new long[0])
                       .putExtras(bundle);
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setLights(0xff00ff00, 300, 100)
            .build();

    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    notificationManager.notify(random, notification);
    }
```

At the receiever end get it as a string load it in your Activity.

```
String url = getArguments.getString("url");
Url myUrl = new Url(url);
```